# Would a communist society work?

Tags: communism, capitalism

I'm pretty sure it would not work immediately after transforming from our current state, but surely over time we should see change, right?

Are there any examples of when it has/hasn't worked?

Comment: Never has yet, hundreds have been tried.

Comment: Communism has only killed 100+ million world wide, let's give it another chance.

Comment: @KDog that isn't my-own-special-variety-of-communism-tailored-to-this-specific-discussion so of course it wouldn't work!  Now if there was only a 'third-way' that didn't yet run it's course we could all try out.. oh wait -- [banned].

Comment: @hownowbrowncow  not really sure what you are advocating.  Perhaps Cuba, Venezuela, Angola, USSR?

Comment: @KDog More like Spain, Italy, Germany.

Comment: "over time" is too broad to be answerable. Will communism work in the current resource constrained world? No. Will it work in post-scarcity society? Maybe, depends on tons of particulars nobody is willing or for that matter able to explore in a single concise SE answer.

Comment: @KDog - It is not communism that killed people.  It was the tolalitarian leadership that killed 100+ million.  Communism, and Democracy take no actions cause no harm.  People take actions and cause harm.  Do not take that as me embracing and endorsing communism or saying it is for everyone.

Answer (score 3):

Certianly.  It works for the Amish, it works on a number of communes around the country and world where people gather as a community and work toward a common survival and existance.

So if it works in these places why doesn't it work in every place? The key to it working in these places is that everyone involved is there by choice and chooses to live like that.  They can also choose to leave that society for another even if doing so would be difficult. The reality is that people choose to stay in those societies knowing there are other options.  Being a choice people are more willing to contribute as expected so that they can remain.

In addition to choosing to stay the society chooses to keep them.  One of major punishments in Amish culture is shunning.  It seems like a minor thing to those of us in an globalized world connected to the internet.  But in Amish society it is a serious punishment reserved for those who have the potential to cause harm to their society.  If you actually cause that harm they could choose to cast you out.

Once you go to a government version there is no longer a choice to participate or not.  And the government can not choose not to include you. So there is no way for the government to make you conform and there is no way for you to decide you do not want to be a part of it.  And that is why communism as a form of government has difficulty succeeding with out resorting to inhumane punishments.

And contrary to a commonly held belief [communism does not require atheism](http://www.huffingtonpost.com/2015/02/02/china-communist-party-atheism-zhejiang-ban-religious-members-christianity_n_6599722.html).

> China recognizes five “official” religions — Buddhism, Taoism, Islam,
>   Protestantism and Catholicism — but many believers who worship outside
>   of state-sanctioned institutions are subject to periodic crackdowns.
>   Buddhism and Taoism have received far greater official support due to
>   their deep roots in Chinese culture

Marxism however does call for the abolition of religion and Marxist communism is was the core of the [Bolshevik revolution in Russia](http://www.marxist.com/bolshevik-revolution-95-years-on.htm), and the foundation of the Soviet Union.  Moaism, the chinese philosophy, is considered by its followers as [an anti-Revisionist form of Marxism–Leninism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maoism).

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/48732/discussion-on-answer-by-deplorablenumber9035768-would-a-communist-society-work).

Comment: As a note of clarification, China has not always been willing to recognize religions, and the stigmas and state sanctions there even today are very strong.